# Swift: Cabeçalho fixo em um TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

O meu problema é o seguinte: minha aplicação possui uma tela que utiliza o layout UITableViewController. Eu criei um cabeçalho (View) para esta tela, no entanto, o cabeçalho não fica fixo no topo da tela. Ou seja, quando eu arrasto a tela para cima/baixo, o cabeçalho também se move para cima/baixo. A minha pergunta é existe alguma forma de manter um subView fixo no topo da tela, sendo que esse subView está em UITableViewController?

ps.: eu tentei essa solução mas não funcionou.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll (scrollView: UIScrollView)  {
    var fixedFrame: CGRect = self.uiTopView.frame;
    fixedFrame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.uiTopView.frame = fixedFrame;
}
```

Comment: Você tem duas opções: se sua tabela possui apenas uma seção, experimente definir o estilo de sua tabela como *plain* e criar uma `UIView` customizada. Caso tenha várias seções, não é possível com um `UITableViewController`, daí você vai precisar ter um `UIViewController` e criar separadamente seu cabeçalho e a tabela.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize uma UIViewController ao invés de uma UITableViewController.

Crie sua tela com a sua view que você quer deixar fixa e sua tableview logo abaixo.

Na sua UIViewController também herde uma UITableViewDelegate e uma UITableViewDataSource.
Coloque sua tableview via IBOutlet na sua ViewController e faça com que sua tableview receba o dataSource e Delegate da sua classe, por exemplo:

self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.delegate = self

Dessa forma a área "Scrollable" será apenas sua tableView e não a sua view inteira.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma ;)

Answer (score -1):

Breno, tente isso:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll (scrollView: UIScrollView)  {
    self.uiTopView.frame.origin.y = max(0.0, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y)
}
```

Não esqueça de adicionar o delegate no scrollView